# Add 50% discount in Total if radio button option is selected (RSForm!Pro)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, discount

I have a RSform!Pro which is working great except for... I need to apply a 50% discount if people select a certain option in a radio button group. I'm using a code that should work as I found it in RSJoomla forum and they say it works. But not for me:

```
$amount=$_POST['form']['rsfp_Total']; 
if($_POST['form']['form[my_radio_button_group]'] == 'option 1')
   $_POST['form']['rsfp_Total'] = $amount - 50%;
```

I also tried this, but nothing still...

```
if($_POST['form']['form[form[my_radio_button_group]'] == 'option 1')
  $_POST['form']['form[Total]'] = $_POST['form']['form[Total]'] - 50%;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You cant subtract with `50%`. Try this:

```
if($_POST['form']['form[form[my_radio_button_group]'] == 'option 1') {
  $var = $_POST['form']['form[Total]'];
  $half = ((float) $var)/2;
  $_POST['form']['form[Total]'] = $half;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $_POST variables can be accessed like this:

```
$_POST['form']['name_of_field']
```

Basically, you can 'hack' the rsfp_total as you described :

```
if ($_POST['form']['radio'] == 'some-choice'){
    $_POST['form']['rsfp_Total'] = $_POST['form']['rsfp_Total'] / 2;
}
```

Or you can send a new argument to paypal like this (the correct way):

```
if ($_POST['form']['radio'] == 'some-choice'){
  $paypal = RSFormProPayPal::getInstance();
  $paypal->args['discount_rate'] = 50;
}
```

You can find more information on this here: https://goo.gl/vi6BPd